# what is the status of the Mathematica stackexchange.com weekly newsletter?

Tags: support, status-completed

**Updated Feb 7, wed. 2018**

I still have not received the weekly Mathematica newsletter. Even thought I am subscribed, and verified my email OK and my profile says I am subscribed. Very strange, I've been getting it for years and now suddenly it stopped.

**Original answer**

I have not received by email the weekly Mathematica newsletter of this forum, which used to come each Tuesday of each week. Last one I got was on January 16, 2018.

Is this news letter still being emailed?  Any one else is getting it? The email comes from   `do-not-reply@stackexchange.com`  and so I really do not know who to ask about this.

**Update**:

I checked I am already subscribed.  I looked at my email settings and found it set as  `userName%domainName@gtempaccount.com`  which is what I see when I login from google. I do not understand this email and why it is like this.

I changed it to my actual email, which is `userName@domainName` and verified it.

So will wait one more week to see.

This is all over my head. I never understood `userName%domainName@gtempaccount.com` and how it works, but this is what google shows me each time I login. I have to login to google first in order to login to stackexchange.com. Why? I do not know.  I wish I do not have to login to google just to login to stackexchange.

I have no need for my google account and do not use any google email or any google anything.  But this is how its been for years now and do not know how to use my own email to login to stackexchange.

Comment: There were [some disturbances](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306231/233085), please check if you are still subscribed.

Comment: @Kuba thanks for the info. I checked and it says I am still subscribed. Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/n7qG0.png) I can try to unsubscribe and then subscribe again?  How does on subscribe? I forgot how I did this first time. If I turn it off, what is next? Is there a separate link to use to subscribe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We recently changed the underlying infrastructure that newsletters runs upon which involved moving a bunch of data from one database to another.

Your subscription was associated with your SE account but the *verified email* we had for your account was the `@tempaccount` address that Google assigned to you. Before the move newsletters were sent with whatever address you entered when you subscribed to them, but now we use the verified email associated with your SE account. Why? Well, for a variety of reasons (mostly CAN-SPAM and other spam law related things), a consistent single verified email address is a lot easier for us to manage all the things we might send to you.

The `@tempaccount.com` whole mess is something to do with Google merging accounts. Likelihood is that when you first logged in with your Google credentials that was the primary email associated with your Google account. If you didn't have a verified email address associated with your SE account at that time we use the first verified email that we find from one of your logins.

Presumably the `@tempaccount` address is no longer associated with your Google account so the newsletters ended up going into a big black hole. Updating your email will fix this, you'll receive the newsletter next week.

Apologies for the inconvenience!

Comment: Thanks. I have another important question, but do not know where to ask it. I want to know how to login to stackexchange using my own personal email (the one now verified as userName@my_domain) without having to login to google first, then come in to stackexchange and click to login again using `google` login tab.   Is this possible? I feel hostage to google now. I can't do anything without having to login to google.  Which forum can I ask this at? Is there place where it describes how one can do this?

Comment: If you navigate to https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current you can add other logins there

Comment: That does not really help. I tried that before. It only shows one the option to use either google., facebook, then lists other companies., then lists something called openID account, which I have no idea what that is. But what I want is to use my own personal email account to login to stackexchange.  Is there a place that discusses how to do this in simple terms one can understand? thanks.

Comment: I don't understand, what login do you want to use, a Stack Exchange login?

Comment: Yes. I want to make just a stackexchange account that I can login to, without having to login to google first. How do I do this?  Is this the OPEN ID thing? Only way I know how to login to stack exchange is to login to google first, then login to stackexchange using google login tab. But I want to keep same user name as I have, keep all my profile etc.. the same.

Comment: fyi, I am still not getting the Mathematica newsletter. Its been over a week. I verified I am subscribed with verified email.

Comment: @Nasser a slight quirk with the formatting of Mathematica newsletters - they include double braces which we detect as an incomplete render (we use placeholders with double braces for parts of the template). That meant the newsletters were skipped. Working on a fix right now

Comment: The Mathematica newsletter came only one time since Feb 8 and then stopped again. Have not seen it for 2 weeks. May be there is a new bug.

Comment: Yup, still an issue with the templating. It’s in the backlog, won’t get to finishing up a fix til next week...

Comment: @Nasser Since January 16th I received too only the February 8h weekly newsletter so I'm sure many people are concerned with . this recurrent problem. Why  a temporary palliative hasn't been set up until the mass mailing problem is solved is beyond me (such as generating the weekly newsletter in a shared cloud directory and then letting know the link to it in a post to the mathematica   Q/A site );