# newsletter is not received

Tags: discussion

I do not know whether we should ask this question here, so sorry if it is not relevant. But this is a problem for me.

I have received Mathematica Stack Exchange Newsletter on Tuesday every week. But the last week I did not receive it. I wanted to register for it again. But this option is not on the web page. I have seen some questions about this problem in 2018, but I did not have any problem until the last week.

How can I solve the problem to receive newsletters again?

Comment: How are you getting the newsletter? I stopped getting it long time ago [what-is-the-status-of-the-mathematica-stackexchange-com-weekly-newsletter](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2286/what-is-the-status-of-the-mathematica-stackexchange-com-weekly-newsletter)  As of Feb 7, wed. 2018 stopped getting it.   I assumed it just stopped for everyone. I was collecting these newsletter for many years but stopped 2 years ago because suddenly they stopped emailing them.

Comment: @Nasser  I have received the Mathematica Stack Exchange Newsletter every week for many years up to 17 March 2020.  I did not receive the 24 March edition, however. I hope that it has not been discontinued, because I find this curated list of top questions very informative.

Comment: I just went and subscribed one more time. Last one I get one was  on Tuesday, January 16, 2018. Do you still have them in your email folder since then? I wonder if so if you could forward them to me since that time so I can update this page [mathematica_stackexchange_letters](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/mathematica_stackexchange_letters/index.htm)  since I do not know if there are stored anywhere. Is there an archive one can go get them from? I did not think so. thanks.

Comment: @Nasser, I am so happy to hear you that you have collected them. I will forward them to you. But if possible please let me I do that step by step. Because the number of such letters are large and it takes long time to find them.

Comment: @Unbelievable thanks, that will be great. I do not know what email client you use. I use thunderbird, and have all the mathematica news letters in one folder in my email. So if you have something similar, you can actually do it all in one shot, by selecting all the email and just do forward. Here is screen shot of mine fyi  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QtEnx.png)  but if you do not have them all in one folder, it might be easier for you to first put them in one folder. But either way, please take your time. any time you can send them is ok.

Comment: I use Gmail account. Upon your suggestion, I add an extension for multiforward "Multi-Forward For Gmail". But it does not work for me correctly.

Comment: I received today's weekly newsletter, so the series has not been cancelled.  I do not know why I or the OP did not receive a copy last Tuesday.

Comment: I received too!!!

Comment: @bbgodfrey and Unbelievable: I just today started getting the newsletter again after subscribing again. Thanks for forwarding me the missing ones.